# Как передать список другому Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

У меня есть RecyclerView1, который выводит список. При нажатии на элемент списка вызывается Fragment, где уже появляется другой RecyclerView2 со своим списком элементов. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на разные элементы RecyclerView1 отображается один и тот же RecyclerView2. Как сделать, чтобы каждому элементу были привязан свои список? Пытался использовать пакет аргументов, но никак не получается.

Comment: в вопросе недостаточно информации: проблемный код,  какой тип данных, где хранятся, как формируются и др. для получения воспроизводимого примера проблемы. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ

Comment: Сделать базу данных и передавать ключ типа названия таблицы итд.

Comment: @Романыч  Спасибо, обязательно попробую!

Comment: @OhHiMark покажите, как делаете